# Detect Authentication exception on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing an app with spring-mvc and spring security.

I'm using this little script in view layer in order to populate a `div` inside my page with html data returned from my controller:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : $("#"+ event.args.element.id+ "Url").val(),
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(data){
        $("#ContentPanel").html(data);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error!!!");
    }
});
```

But if the user in not authenticated (for example because of session expiration), the div is populated with html from login page. How can avoid it, and let spring give such error information to the script in the view?

Here is my spring security configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"  
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/url1**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/url2/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref bean="authenticationProvider"/>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="it.cpmapave.fgas.aziende.service.jpa.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>



<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: configure spring security to send a redirect status code 303, check the status code in ajax call and take an appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the 401 or 404 after a bad authorization Spring returns 403 resource not accesible

```
       $.ajax({
       type : "GET",
       url : url,
       statusCode : {

       200 : function() {
          alert("Successfull access.");
       },
       401 : function() {
          alert("Unauthorised access.");
       },

       403 : function() {
          alert("Forbidden resouce can't be accessed");
       }
       });

       };
```

In any case if you have a form defined on Spring security you can tell the form which page have to go in case or login failure.

```
              <form-login
                login-processing-url="/doLogin.do"
                login-page="/login.do"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"
                default-target-url="/foo.do"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
            />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @paul, but it doesn't works. I have updated my question with more details..